# Next.js App router cache revalidation problems

Tags: caching, next.js, vercel, app-router

So guys, sorry for the dumb question. I am trying to get familiar with the new app router technology of Next.js. Point is, everything works perfectly fine on localhost and the tech is actually amazing compared to page router.

But when I deploy it on vercel, I can't get revalidatePath to do its job properly. It's just absolute chaos. Sometimes I need to refresh the page, and it's ok; some other times I need to force revalidation again AND refresh the page a couple of time. And I have to do it on every page I ask nextjs to revalidate the cache with revalidatePath. I mean, it's worse than hell.

It's the first time I write on stack overflow. Should I write and share some simple example project in order to give you a thorough perspective of the problem?

I tried to build a server action which changes pieces of data in more than one page of my app and use revalidatePath inside the action in order to revalidate such pieces of data.

Something like that:

```
'use server'

export async function action(formdata: FormData) {
    //change data in db;
    revalidatePath('/');
}
```

On localhost everything works properly. When I deploy the project on Vercel, it does not. Data is generally not revalidated, unless I repeat the process more than once and I refresh every page involved in revalidation more than once.

Thanks a lot! Tell me if you need more information.

Comment: Ok, I think the problem is in the way I fetch data from the db: I do not use the fetch API, but I use mongoDB standard methods. I need to cache the fetching requests in the proper way.

Comment: it is not related to how you fetch. in production, there is full route cache: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#1-react-rendering-on-the-server

Comment: I can attest, revalidation on the Vercel Data Cache is absolute chaos. Everything works perfectly locally even with build/start but Vercel just messes up.